# Similar implementations of one trait for many structs

Tags: rust

In the below code the only different in implementation is in the `println!`.

It feels like there should be a way for me not to have to write out two completely different implementations, however I have not found a way.

```
pub trait ChangeDecision{
    fn change_decision(&mut self);
}

impl ChangeDecision for Hero{
    fn change_decision(&mut self){
        self.should_change_decision = false;
        let rand_num = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101) as f32 / 100.;
        let mut prob_counter = 0.0;
        for (action, prob) in &mut self.decisions.iter(){
            prob_counter += *prob;
            match prob_counter{
                p if rand_num > p => {},
                _ => {println!("{}: {:?}", self.name, action); self.current_decision = *action; break},
            }
        }
    }
}

impl ChangeDecision for Team{
    fn change_decision(&mut self){
        self.should_change_decision = false;
        let rand_num = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101) as f32 / 100.;
        let mut prob_counter = 0.0;
        for (action, prob) in &mut self.decisions.iter(){
            prob_counter += *prob;
            match prob_counter{
                p if rand_num > p => {},
                _ => {println!("{:?}: {:?}", self.side, action); self.current_decision = *action; break},
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the implementations are exactly identical I can use a macro to implement for both. i.e.

```
macro_rules! impl_SimilarStuff {
    ($T:ident) => {
        impl SimilarStuff for $T{
            fn my_func(&mut self){
                true
            }
        }
     }
}

impl_SimilarStuff!(ThingOne);
impl_SimilarStuff!(ThingTwo);
```

However I could not find any examples of 'macro conditionality'

Answer (score 2):

The way I would handle this is to use another trait to handle the differing parts.  Something like:

```
trait PrintSomething {
    fn print_something(&self, action: Action);
}

impl PrintSomething for Hero {
    fn print_something(&self, action: Action) {
        println!("{}: {:?}", self.name, action);
    }
}

impl PrintSomething for Team {
    fn print_something(&self, action: Action) {
        println!("{}: {:?}", self.side, action);
    }
}

// Now the macro would expand to:
impl ChangeDecision for Hero {
    fn change_decision(&mut self){
        self.should_change_decision = false;
        let rand_num = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 101) as f32 / 100.;
        let mut prob_counter = 0.0;
        for (action, prob) in &mut self.decisions.iter(){
            prob_counter += *prob;
            match prob_counter{
                p if rand_num > p => {},
                _ => {
                    self.print_something(action);
                    self.current_decision = *action;
                    break
                 },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. this seems very sensible.

I could also add the print something function, to the Change Decision trait and call it.

This would mean I wouldnt need to add a new trait for it, however I'm not sure if multiple functions for one trait is good practice/easy to read

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the "conditional" parts to your macros as separate parameters. Along the lines of:

```
struct S1 {n1 : isize}
struct S2 {n2 : isize}

trait T {
    fn print_me(self);
}

macro_rules! doit {
    ($t: ty, $member: ident) => (
        impl T for $t {
            fn print_me(self) {
                println!("{}", self.$member);
            }
        }
    )
}

doit!(S1, n1);
doit!(S2, n2);

fn main() {
    let s1 = S1 {n1: 1};
    let s2 = S2 {n2: 2};
    s1.print_me();
    s2.print_me();
}
```

If the "custom part" is bigger than some simple statements, you may consider extracting the custom part into an own trait, as suggested by @Chris Emerson.

Alternatively, you might try to write a generic function taking a something satisfying your trait and the custom part as a closure. This, however, may involve modifying your trait.